# JPA Error: InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities mapped to one another using the `oneToMany` annotation. One entity is `bookedBus` and the second is `drivers` The drivers entity would already have a row inserted into that would later become a foreign reference (FK) to bookedBus entity(PK). Below are the two entities, setters and getter have been skipped for brevity.

First entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bookedBuses")
public class BookedBuses implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "driver_id")
    private Drivers driver;
}
```

Second entity

```
@Entity
public class Drivers implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "driver")
    private List<BookedBuses> bookedBus;
}
```

Now When I try to save to the booked bus entity it throws the following exception

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.bus.api.entity.Drivers; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.bus.api.entity.Drivers

Below is how I tried saving to the bookedBus entity

```
BookedBuses bookedRecord = new BookedBuses();
bookedRecord.setBookedSeats(1);
bookedRecord.setBookedBusState(BookedBusState.LOADING);
      bookedRecord.setBus(busService.getBusByPlateNumber(booking.getPlateNumber()));
bookedRecord.setRoute(booking.getRoute());
 infoLogger.info("GETTING DRIVER ID ======= " +    booking.getDriver().getId());
 Drivers drivers = new Drivers(booking.getDriver().getId());
 List<BookedBuses> d_bu = new ArrayList<>();
 drivers.setBooked(d_bu);
 drivers.addBooked(bookedRecord);
 bookedRecord.setDriver(drivers);
 bookedBusService.save(bookedRecord);
```

My BookBusService Save Method as requested

```
@Autowired
private BookedBusRepository bookedBusRepo;
public boolean save(BookedBuses bookedRecord) {
    try {
        bookedBusRepo.save(bookedRecord);
        return true;
    } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
        AppConfig.LOGGER.error(ex);
        return false;
        // Log error message
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code of bookedBusService.save

Comment: @SimonMartinelli done, check it please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st you have some mix up in naming: you have `Driver` & `Drivers`. Like this:

```
private Drivers driver;
```

Also selecting variable names like this:

```
BookedBuses bookedRecord = new BookedBuses();
```

will cause a lot of confusion. Do not mix plural & singular between types and preferably also do not introduce names that might not be easily associated like record. Also this:

```
private List<BookedBuses> bookedBus;
```

which should rather be like:

```
private List<BookedBus> bookedBuses;
```

(and would alsoi require change to your class name BookedBuses -> BookedBus)

Anyway the actual problem seems to lie here:

```
Drivers drivers = new Drivers(booking.getDriver().getId());
```

You need to fetch existing entity by id with a help of repository instead of creating a new one with id of existing. So something like:

```
Drivers drivers = driverRepo.findOne(booking.getDriver().getId()); // or findById(..)
```

It seems that you have a constructor (that you did not show) that enables to create a driver with id. That is not managed it is considered as detached. (You also have `drivers.addBooked(bookedRecord);` which you did not share but maybe it is trivial)

**Note also** some posts suggest to change`CascadeType.ALL` to `CascadeType.MERGE` whether that works depends on your needs. Spring data is able to do some merging on `save(..)` based on entity id but not necessarily in this case.

Answer (score 2):

This line

`Drivers drivers = new Drivers(booking.getDriver().getId());`

If you already have the driver ID available with you then there's no need to pull the driver ID again from the DB.

After removing the `Cascade` attribute from `@OneToMany` & `@ManyToOne` your code should work.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bookedBuses")
public class BookedBuses implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
`
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "driver_id")
    private Drivers driver;
}

@Entity
public class Drivers implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "driver_id")
    private List<BookedBuses> bookedBus;
}
```